# python for statement with if inside it

Tags: django, for-loop, if-statement, statements

Need help please. I'm trying to get this if statement within a for statement correct, but failing miserably at it. If an image isn't available, I badly need a fallback image to replace it.

Thank you

```
{% for post in posts|slice:":1" %}
    <div class="container">
        {% if post.image.url %}
        <div class="flex-item">
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img style="width:100%;" src="{{ post.image.url }}"</a>
        </div>
        {% else %}
       <div class="image-container1">
            <img src="{% static 'images/fallback.png' %}" alt="" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;display: block;">
        </div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And please read [ask]. How is this failing to do what you want?

Comment: it keeps searching for the image and ignores the static part of the code. Looking through the how to ask link.

Comment: What does "it keeps searching for the image" mean? What attributes does a `post` have that exhibits the behaviour you're describing? Are you entirely sure its `image.url` is falsy?

Comment: it's sorted, the trick is to use {% if post.image.url is not None %}

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing a div, which you opened just after first loop, also assuming that you are loading static on top.

P.S. I can't add comment, so posting it as ans.